# select Multi-Value Select Boxes using cypress

Tags: multi-select, cypress

I could not select Multi-Value Select Boxes (http://select2.github.io/select2/)

I try:

```
cy.get('s2id_e9').click()
cy.get('ul li:first').contains('California').select()
```

but it does not work.

**How can I select these options? Hope someone can help?**

Comment: Please give details of the error given in Cypress.

Answer (score 1):

```
cy.get('#s2id_e9 ul.select2-choices').click()
cy.contains('.select2-result-label', 'California').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for multi select dropdowns

```
  cy.get('[name="Optionwithcheck[]"]').select(['Option 2','Option 3'])
```